# Postgres сортировка при наличии №

Tags: postgresql

как у постгре при сортировке сделать чтобы № не ставился после N ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

№ разпознается как No

мне # и № вместе нужно поставить

pg v 9.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *, replace(name, '№', '0') as alias_name
FROM web.series
ORDER BY alias_name
```